# How to add custom class array into multidimensional array swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I had firebase database structure like this:

[image]

Currently I'm fetching the top key which is categories, But I want it to make dynamic when network call when selecting picker based on its categories and display on tableview, Is there any way to do that in swift3? But somehow I figure out by adding it in array.

my question is how do I convert array to multidimensional array?

```
  func getCategories() {
    DataService.ds.REF_CATEGORIES.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in
      if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
        for (_, item) in snapshot.enumerated().reversed() {
          let key = item.key.capitalized
          self.categories.append(key)
          print("key --> \(key)")
           if let catDict = item.value as? JSONDictionary {
            let count = catDict.count
            for i in catDict {
              if let finalCat = i.value as? JSONDictionary {
                let finalKey = i.key
                let category = Pizza(categoriesKey: finalKey , categoriesData: finalCat)
                self.multiCat.append([category])
                print("multiCat --> \(self.multiCat)")
                print("i count --> \(count)")
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

**Console Log:** multiCat --> [[Pizza,Pizza,Pizza,Pizza,Pizza,Pizza,Pizza,Pizza,Pizza,]]

**What I want is: [[Pizza,Pizza,Pizza], [Pizza,Pizza,Pizza], [Pizza,Pizza,Pizza,]]**

Comment: Are you sure you need a multi-dimensional array? It looks like an array of Dicts, Structures, or classes would work. Or even an array of other array's if you want a guaranteed sequence.

Comment: @jay I think yes because what I need is to display the item based on its categories like we say when selecting a pickerView it will list all categories and for example selecting a "Other" in categories it should be display the item in tableView. So I think I need only 1 variable (self.multiCat is an array of class) to fetch all data. then call them like self.multiCat[0] for the "Other" categories like picture in database. There is any way to do that?